# Why is my Eclipse Program terminating?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, while-loop

I'm a novice coder looking for some help. I had to write this program where the user guesses a number between 0 and 100 and then in response is told if it is higher or lower. Below is the code. My question is, sometimes when I put in a number, usually 99 the program terminates and I have no idea why. I have been looking at the code for 2 hours and cannot figure out what causes the program to terminate. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Proj71 {
  private static int userNumber;
  private static int firstguess = 1;
  private static int numguess1;
  private static int numguess2;
  private static int totalguess;
  private static Random generator = new Random();
  private static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static int compNumber = generator.nextInt(100);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserGuess();
    UserHighGuess();
    UserLowGuess();
    UserEquals();
  }
  private static void UserGuess() {
    System.out.println("What number am I thinking of between 0 and 100?: ");
    userNumber = reader.nextInt();
  }
  private static void UserHighGuess() {
    while (userNumber > compNumber) {
      System.out.println("Lower! Try again: ");
      userNumber = reader.nextInt();
      numguess1++;
    }
  }
  private static void UserLowGuess() {
    while (userNumber < compNumber) {
      System.out.println("Higher! Try again: ");
      userNumber = reader.nextInt();
      numguess2++;
    }
  }
  private static void UserEquals() {
    if (userNumber == compNumber) {
      totalguess = numguess1 + numguess2 + firstguess;
      System.out.println("You got it!");
      System.out.println("Total number of guess: " + totalguess);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Jmanlikescake (sorry if this post is really bad)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: This looks like java, you should tag it as such if you want the right people to see it (I went ahead and did that for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the structure of the program.

You are calling

```
UserGuess();
UserHighGuess();
UserLowGuess();
UserEquals();
```

What if the number was 50, and the user guessed 30? We'd be in the body of UserLowGuess().
Then imagine the user entered 55. The UserLowGuess() would be broken out of as the userNumber is greater than the compNumber. So then, you would be in UserEquals. But since 55 is not equal to 50, the if statement will not be entered and the program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting this into one while loop, not three.  I haven't tested this, FYI.

This loops continuously accepting user input until a match is found.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserGuess();
}

private static void UserGuess() {
    System.out.println("What number am I thinking of between 0 and 100?: ");
    userNumber = reader.nextInt();
    totalguess = 1;
    while (userNumber != compNumber) {
        if (userNumber > compNumber) {
            System.out.println("Lower! Try again: ");
        } else if (userNumber < compNumber) {
            System.out.println("Higher! Try again: ");
        }
        userNumber = reader.nextInt();
        totalguess++;
    }
    System.out.println("You got it!");
    System.out.println("Total number of guess: " + totalguess);
}
```